# Why my data in Excel is not the same when I import using wizard in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I want to copy the data from Excel to SQL Server using wizard. However, the data is not same when I import to SQL Server. Can someone help me how to solve it?

[image: this is excel data]

[image: this is sql data]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds after the date? Change the data type of that column when importing.

Comment: yeah that is the problem, I already change the type. i change to custom> dd/mm/yyyy. i t works on excel but after i import in SQL Server the data has change.@SQL_Underworld

Comment: This may not help, but in my years of experience, you can't trust the import / export wizard in either direction. Or, you can IF you know for sure what the data is like. There're always problems with escape / tab / other special characters, encoding, data types, and excels habituary problem of forced data conversion. The best way to move data is by customized solutions you make yourself. In this scenario, if the dataset is small enough, I'd almost recommend concatenating the columns into an INSERT statement to a temp table, then edit the columns properly with TSQL and go from there.

Comment: owh really, so there no solution for my prob. it is the huge data and impossible for me to do it manually. btw thanks:) @Kahn

Comment: There's always a solution, it's just about how much duct tape it may sometimes require. :) Can you elaborate on WHAT has changed? The accurracy of the milliseconds? The entire value of the column? Hard to propose an exact solution until we know what's going on.

Comment: I have change the due date column "data type" to date format dd/mm/yyyy. it works on excel like in the picture. But if i import it to SQl Server the data shown like above. I dunno why because in excel it look fine. @Kahn

Comment: i just want the date only not the time.@Kahn

Answer (score 1):

So by the comments, the problem is that after you changed the excel data type to date, it still gets exported as datetime?

Sounds like what you changed was how the data was displayed in excel, but the real data is still stored in datetime, which then gets moved as such as you export it. You can check this by clicking on a cell with the data, and looking at the white bar on top of page. That should show you whatever data or formula is *actually* in that cell. If it's as I suspect, then this is intended working behaviour.

The good news is that:

1. Storing datetime data as date in SQL Server, gets converted automatically. No manual labor required.
2. You can for instance add a new field in excel, use SUBSTR function to capture the DATE part only from the datetime field, and use that in place of the actual datetime during export.
3. If you export the data into what now becomes a datetime column instead of a date column, into some kind of a temporary table in SQL Server, you could simply ALTER the column type to date as part of the process.

Take your pick. :)

Comment: can I know, where is is the white bar? i have check the type. it show the custom. hurmmm.@Kahn

Comment: It's called the formula bar, you can find instructions here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/01/21/formula-bar-excel/

Comment: when i choose the cell 16/9/2006 it show 9/16/2006. whats means by that?@Kahn

Comment: Ah, in that case it sounds as though  the data really is date, but gets exported (or imported, on SQL Server side) as datetime.

Comment: so, the problem is the sql server? what should i do now? sorry i keep asking cause im totally lost. @Kahn

Comment: i think i found the solution. thank you for your help. @Kahn

Comment: What happens when you change the data type of the column in SQL Server?